Freeze after boot and slow text input
For a while now my Ubuntu 22.04.4 is rather sluggish.
Directly after booting and logging in, the desktop freezes for 10 - 20 seconds; completely at first, after ~5 seconds I can move the cursor, but not interact with anything.
After that, the screen briefly goes all gray, before appearing again (I stronly assume that Gnome is restarting here).
One interesting thing I noticed is that the desktop always freezes just before the docks (the sidebar on the left) initial slide-in animation finishes.
After reappearing, it overall runs normally except some things are slow/sluggish sometimes. The problem is not consistent. The system is slow for a minute or maybe a few and then might work just fine for an hour, before going slow again.
It's really hard to time exactly and I also can't trigger the "slowness".
The things I notice the most is text input, especially in terminals it's noticably delayed or sometimes single key strokes, especially right when starting to type are occasionally missed entirely.
This happens in the regular terminal, in the standard editor as well as in PHPstorms built in terminal. The code editor part of PHPstorm seems not to be affected or at least not that noticably.
I also noticed that sometimes (but much less often than the text input issue) parts of the UI flicker.
One example was in the text editor: on hitting enter, the line flickered back and forth a few times (going to the next line and going back to the current line, 2-3 times).
Another example is that highlighted text or lines stay highlighted for a while, even after changing the selection or line. On input the highlight appears/disapears a few times before finally disappearing.
Generally, the issues seems to be mostly related to text input.
This started after doing an apt full-upgrade a while ago. Previously, everything was fast and responsive.
Infos:
I originaly thought my problem might be similar to Ubuntu 22.04.4 running very slow after update from 22.04.2 but they seem to have low CPU clock speeds while I do not seem to.
I added the infos requested there anyways, since I do not really know where else to start.
If there is any additional information necessary/helpfull please let me know in a comment and I will add it.
fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  20
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-19
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-13600K
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               183
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  14
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    CPU max MHz:         3900,0000
    CPU min MHz:         800,0000
    BogoMIPS:            6988.80
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss h
                         t tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_ts
                         c cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr 
                         pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefe
                         tch cpuid_fault invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad 
                         fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt x
                         savec xgetbv1 xsaves avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req umip pk
                         u ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq tme rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize pconfig arch_lbr flush
                         _l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   544 KiB (14 instances)
  L1i:                   704 KiB (14 instances)
  L2:                    20 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    24 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-19
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected

fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate

fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave

fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/base_frequency:2600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:3840915
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3009801
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>

fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:21
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active

fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4472514
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4507283
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:5100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3900204
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3913377
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3899037
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3901133
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3899911
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3900428
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3917187
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3903448
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:5100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3999431
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:801095
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4109492
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:2509041
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4227254
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4820161
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:3271716
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:5112592

I ran it multiple times and the values seem to jump quiet a bit. Here's a 10 seconds gif of the frequencies. (For some reason I can not upload the image directly)
fitzi@Fitzi-PC:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^[c]pu MHz"
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3167.657
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000
cpu MHz     : 3500.000

When watching with watch -n.5 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep \"^[c]pu MHz\"" speed are stable at 3500 with occasional short boosts and drops on single cores. Here's a 10 seconds gif of it.

Things I tried so far
I was trying to screen record some of the glitches and flickers, but interestingly recording the screen seems to prevent them. Might just be a coincidence though. I recorded with SimpleScreenRecorder.
In /var/log/kern.log I found a lot of docker related messages. At first I thought that they might slow down the system and after stopping docker, the system seemed to be snappier at first.
I then tried to disable docker autostart and reboot a few times. At first I thought this fixed the problem, since the system booted normally and was usable immediately. But after 3-4 reboots the problem appeared again,
even with docker still disabled. I'm not sure what to do with this information. Could this be an indicator to a problem with docker or was this just a coincidence?
Since then, the system froze right on boot every single time again.
In /var/log/syslog ther are occasioanly messages that the system is too slow (probably a symptom of the underlying problem?)
Apr 16 08:24:16 Fitzi-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2571]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-20ms), your system is too slow
Apr 16 08:35:10 Fitzi-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2571]: (EE) event4  - Logitech M720 Triathlon: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 21ms, your system is too slow
Apr 16 08:36:00 Fitzi-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2571]: (EE) event4  - Logitech M720 Triathlon: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 24ms, your system is too slow
Apr 16 08:36:13 Fitzi-PC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2571]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-27ms), your system is too slow

I tried watching some other log files for a while to see if they might get flooed. I did not notice any especially large amount of log messages that would justify slowing the system down that much though.
I checked the Gaphics driver. In the past I had problems with the GUI being slow with the Nouveau driver. According to lshw -c video the driver used is still the nvdia one. I assume this is not the problem, I can't rule it out certainly though.
I'm dual booting this machine. On windows none of the problems appear, so I'm pretty sure that it's not a hardware fault.

What could be the problem causing this?
What can I do to fix the problem?
